# Reliably match an url inside a line

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm having some trouble figuring out what I thought to be pretty simple regex. I'm trying to make a Twitter bot in Python that tweets quotes from some author. 
I need it to:

- read a quote and an url from a file
- parse the quote and the url apart so that it can add quotes marks
  around the quote part and use the url part to determine which book
  the quote is from and add the relevant book cover
- I also need to get the url apart to calculate the tweet length after
  twitter shortened the url
- One last thing: some quotes might not have url, I need it to identify that and add some random pics as a fallback.

After trials and errors, I came up with this regex that seemed to do the job when I tested it : `r'(?P<quote>.*)(?P<link>https.*)?'`

Since I don't need to validate url I don't think that I need any complicated regex like the ones I came across in my research.

But when I tried to fire up the bot, I realized it won't parse the quote correctly, and instead catch the whole line as "quote" (and failing to identify the url).

What puzzles me is that it doesn't fail consistently, instead it seems that sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do that fails unreliably: https://regex101.com/r/mODPUq/1/

Here is the whole function I've written:

```
def parseText(text):
    # Separate the quote from the link
    tweet = {}
    regex = r'(?P<quote>.*)?(?P<link>https.*)?'

    m = re.search(regex, text)

    tweet = m.groupdict("")

    return tweet
```

[EDIT] Ok I didn't quite solve the problem this way but found a workaround that might not be very elegant but at least seem to do the job :

- I have 2 separate functions, one to get the url, the other to split the url out of the line and return the quote alone.
- I first call `getUrl()`, and then only if it returns something that is not `None`, I call `getQuote()`. If `url == None`, I can directly tweet the whole line.

This way the regex part became very straightforward, and it seems to work so far with or without url. I just have one minor issue, when there's no url even if I use `str.split('/n')` to cut out the newline character it must still be there, because when I add quotes mark the last one is on a newline.

I leave the issue open for now since technically it's not resolved, thanks to those that gave me answer but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It matches the whole line because the first `.*` is greedy and the second group is optional and so is the following `.*`. If you want to match the http part, you might use `https?\S+`

Comment: Yep, just change the greedy quantifier `.*` to a lazy one `.*?` in the `<quote>` group, and that'll do it.

Comment: Hi thanks you for your suggestions, unfortunately it doesn't seem to quite cut it in the debugger at least. I see there's indeed something wrong with the greedy quantifier, but just making it lazy seems to make it catch every single character one at a time.
I found a workaround anyway, see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also change regex string to `r'(?P<quote>.*)?.(?P<link>https.*)'` which also takes care of any extra characters between the quote and the link

Comment: Thanks, I try to make the url stick right after the quote, so it shouldn't be an issue anyway.